# python loop in print argument

Tags: python, iterator

I think thats easy for advanced pythoners, but I can't find it (mainly because i don't know how to name the problem:

```
fruits = ['banana','apple','lemon']

print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % ('peach',[x for x in fruits]))
```

This of course doesn't work, because the left part is filled:

```
> 'peach',['banana','apple','lemon'],???,??? <
```

So this error causes:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string (only two of fours %s' are filled

This is what I want:

```
> 'peach','banana','apple','lemon' <
```

1. How to do it properly?
2. What is the name of part after % `('peach',[x for x in fruit])`?
3. What is the name of part before % `"%s,%s,%s,%s"`? "Format string"?

**UPDATE**

[x for x in fruits] is just easy example - the real for is more complex:

```
fruits = ['banana','apple','lemon']

for i in fruits:
  count[i] = 'one'

print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % ('two',[count[x] for x in fruits]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple wayt to do it.  You basically want to create a tuple for the `%` operator:

```
>>> fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'lemon']

>>> print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % tuple(['peach'] + fruits))
> peach,banana,apple,lemon <

>>> print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % (('peach',) + tuple(fruits)))
> peach,banana,apple,lemon <
>>>
```

Edit:  If you want to do something fancier that requires a comprehension, it's not a problem:

```
>>> print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % (('peach',) + tuple(x for x in fruits)))
> peach,banana,apple,lemon <

>>> print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % (('peach',) + tuple(x.upper() for x in fruits)))
> peach,BANANA,APPLE,LEMON <
```

Edit: If you want to use new style formats, you can do:

```
>>> print("> {},{},{},{} <".format('peach', *[x.upper() for x in fruits]))
> peach,BANANA,APPLE,LEMON <
```

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense.  I updated my answer to show how it's done with comprehensions.  The last example maps the names in `fruits` to uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

You should concatenate two tuples:

```
print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % (('peach',) + tuple(x for x in fruits)))
```

`%s` is called a `conversion specifier`.
What comes after `%` is called a `mapping key`.
What is inside of the quotation marks is a `format string`.

(Terms taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations))

Using `%` for formatting is deprecated as of Python2.6 I believe.  Instead, use `.format()`:

```
print("> {},{},{},{} <".format('peach', *[x for x in fruits]))
```

I can't believe I missed it, but as was mentioned in a comment, you don't need to use a list comprehension.  You can just use `fruits`:

```
print("> %s,%s,%s,%s <" % (('peach',) + tuple(fruits)))
```

and

```
print("> {},{},{},{} <".format('peach', *fruits))
```